# AppShell InitializeComponent Missing in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app-shell

I'm a new developer and I'm developing a xamarin forms app. I have some issues in my app.

I didn't use AppShell navigation at first, I used PushModalAsync() method to navigate between pages but now when user want to go home screen of phone then come back later to my application, it restarts the application. I tried another application and I saw that app uses appshell and it works good I mean it works as I want. When navigate from background It continue where it stay.

So now I want to add AppShell Navigation to my xamarin forms app but this InitializeComponent() missing in my AppShell.xaml.cs file.

Should I open a new project or is there any way to add this to my existing app easyly ?

[image]

AppShell.xaml

```
<Shell  xmlns:xaml="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" 
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:İdaServis.View"
         FlyoutWidth="400"
         FlyoutHeight="200">
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style  TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

        <!--
        Default Styles for all Flyout Items
        https://docs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyoutitem-and-menuitem-style-classes
        -->
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
       
        <!--
        Custom Style you can apply to any Flyout Item
        -->
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
<FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Browse" >
    <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="ProfilePage" >
    <ShellContent Route="ProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:ProfilePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="AdminPage" >
    <ShellContent Route="AdminPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:AdminPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="BarkodOzetTabbedPage" >
    <ShellContent Route="BarkodOzetTabbedPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:BarkodOzetTabbedPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="DepoAktarmaPage" >
    <ShellContent Route="DepoAktarmaPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:DepoAktarımBarkodPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="RaporSecimPage" >
    <ShellContent Route="RaporSecimPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:RaporSecimPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="RaporDetailpage" >
    <ShellContent Route="RaporDetailpage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:RaporDetailPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="SayimEvrakSec" >
    <ShellContent Route="SayimEvrakSec" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SayimGirisEvrakSec}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="SayimEvrakPage" >
    <ShellContent Route="SayimEvrakPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:SayimGirisEvrak}" />
</FlyoutItem>




<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Please [don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). It's okay to take a screenshot of the error, like in this particular instance, but you should still provide the relevant code and any error messages as text anyway. What does the AppShell.xaml file look like? Do you see any other errors apart from the red scriggly underline?

Comment: I can't show error when it was a text, then I add as a picture that time. If I'm wrong sorry. I add appshell.xaml file now. You can check. There is nothing red underline code in appshell.xaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AppShell.xaml is missing the `x:Class` attribute specifying the class name. This is required for the `partial` class to have the XAML as a complementary part:

```xml
<Shell xmlns:xaml="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" 
       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:view="clr-namespace:İdaServis.View"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       x:Class="YourAppNamespace.AppShell">
```

Just replace the "YourAppNamespace" with the actual namespace where the C# part of your `AppShell` class lives.

After this, the `InitializeComponent()` method should become available.